# How to create a bootable Windows usb from Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, bootable

I have a Windows 7 iso file which I wish to burn into a usb to make it bootable. I tried with the Disks utility "Restore Disk Image" and it copied the iso files into the drive but it didn't make it bootable. I tried using Etcher but when I selected the Windows iso file I got a message saying that Windows iso files required a special burning process to make them bootable and that I had to use a tool such as Rufus which isn't available for Linux and Wine couldn't run it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I always use `dd` for this, and it has never failed. Yes, it works for Windows ISO's too.

Here's how I normally go about it (as root -or use `sudo`):

```
dd if=/path/to/your/iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M;
```

The `X` in `sdX` is the where your USB device is connected. Be **very careful** tho choose the right one! Otherwise you might overwrite the wrong disk/partition.

One way to find out the right device is to issue `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/`.

Below is an example, where you see that the USB device is located on `/dev/sdb`:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
totalt 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 11 okt 12.36 ata-MATSHITADVD-RAM_UJ-842S -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 11 okt 12.37 ata-TOSHIBA_MK8009GAH_Z8A1W9THW -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 11 okt 12.37 ata-TOSHIBA_MK8009GAH_Z8A1W9THW-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 11 okt 12.37 ata-TOSHIBA_MK8009GAH_Z8A1W9THW-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 11 okt 12.37 ata-TOSHIBA_MK8009GAH_Z8A1W9THW-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 11 okt 12.41 usb-SanDisk_U3_Cruzer_Micro_3512330F5580ED45-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 11 okt 12.41 usb-SanDisk_U3_Cruzer_Micro_3512330F5580ED45-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 11 okt 12.41 usb-SanDisk_U3_Cruzer_Micro_3512330F5580ED45-0:1 -> ../../sr1
```

Edit: [**The Arch Wiki has a good guide for this**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#Using_dd).

Comment: You can also use the /dev/disk/by-id/ names directly with dd. So just do `dd if=/path/to/your/iso of=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-SanDisk_U3_Cruzer_Micro_3512330F5580ED45-0:0 bs=4M`

Comment: @masgo Thanks buddy, you taught me something new!

Comment: the `/disk/by-id/` is really great. Also for things like software RAID systems, fstab, etc. You always get exactly the drive you expect. If the drive is not there you will get a decent error message. While using /dev/sdX causes a lot of trouble if you replace the drive, or if you re-wire your drives. - The only real drawback is: if you clone your drive and replace it with the clone it will not work until you changed your config - but I like this sort of explicit handling.