# Create Bootable ISO of CentOS Installation

Tags: centos, iso, bootable

My use case is as follows: -
I have a running CentOS 7 system with some packages and customizations. I need to make it into a bootable ISO USB so that next time I plug the USB into a bare metal machine, I have the same system I had with all the packages and customizations.

Here is what I have so far.

- A tool called Mondo Backup (https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-clone-linux-systems/). I did all the steps and got the ISO image in the end, but when I tried to burn it as a bootable USB, it gave me an error saying image wasn't boot compatible.
- Alternatively, I can even have the original OS installed in a VM and use tools like VMWare Workstation to make a bootable ISO. I found this (https://www.howtoforge.com/converting-a-vmware-image-to-a-physical-machine) but wasn't able to get it to work.
- There are multiple unanswered questions similar to this on Stack Exchange ([How to create a bootable Windows usb from Linux Mint?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354105/how-to-create-a-bootable-windows-usb-from-linux-mint)), but since they are 2 years old and don't have an answer, please don't mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Making a custom liveDVD with Ubuntu is fairly easy, here is a howto for similar steps for a Fedora system, which should be close enough to CentOS - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD

Comment: @ivanivan So the OS I have has KVM installed and VM's on top of that with OpenStack installed. I want to preserve the state of the VM's as well as part of the ISO image. I tried with the Kickstarter files that you mentioned in the link, but it doesn't satisfy my requirement.