# Unable to create bootable windows usb from linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, live-usb

I'm currently running linux mint but want to install windows and run dual boot. But having difficulties create a bootable usb.

What I did:

1. format usb to NTFS (also tried FAT32)
2. burn iso to usb with dd from this [anwser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354105/how-to-create-a-bootable-windows-usb-from-linux-mint)
3. reboot and go to BIOS disable boot from mint
4. reboot

Black screen display insert bootable media even I have my usb inserted, can someone let me know what did I missed? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: install windows OS from usb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a program call WOEUSB. It's a Linux based gui for doing exactly what you want.
Here's the Link https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is first getting a Windows ISO with UEFI. Then when
formatting the drive, make sure to use Partition Scheme GPT. This link also helped:

https://onetransistor.eu/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html

Good luck.

Comment: I used GParted to format to ntfs and finally worked!